# how do i store all loop variables in dictionary of python to use in django

Tags: python, django, dictionary

**PYTHON**

```
import requests
import re
import os
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
}
searche=['note 8 pro','note 9 pro','boat','realme','poco']
for d in searche:
    truelink = d.replace(" ","-")
    truelinkk=('https://www.olx.in/hyderabad_g4058526/q-'+truelink+'?isSearchCall=true')
    r = requests.get(truelinkk,headers=headers).text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
    mobile=soup.find_all('li',class_='EIR5N')
    for  note9maxpro in mobile:
        mobi= note9maxpro.find('span',class_='_2tW1I').text
        price= note9maxpro.find('span',class_='_89yzn').text
        date= note9maxpro.find('span',class_='zLvFQ').text
        link=note9maxpro.a.get('href')
        orglink='https://www.olx.in'+link
        price = price.replace("₹ ","")
```

how to store all loop variables in  dictionary of python to use in django
later i want to use this data in django as. please give me solution to reduce lines of my code as well Thanks in advance

```
for i in data:
 i.mobi
 i.price
 i.date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append them to a list?

```py
for d in searche:
    # (your code here)    

    data = list()
    
    for note9maxpro in mobile:
        element = dict()
        element["mobi"] = note9maxpro.find('span',class_='_2tW1I').text
        element["price"] = note9maxpro.find('span',class_='_89yzn').text
        # and so on
        data.append(element)
```

Comment: i am not able get data after loop if i use like this 
for i in data:
    print(i.image)
    print(i.date)  NameError: name 'date' is not defined

Comment: That is not how you call dictionary keys in Python. Try `i["date"]`.

Comment: now working Thankyou very much  fsimonjetz. i have a question we are saving data in list how are we getting data in dictionary please can you answer me

Comment: i am new to stackoveroflow also i want to appreciate you answer what can i do in this post ?

Comment: There should be a check mark next to my answer, if you click that it marks it as accepted. Thank you! Regarding your question: If you need all the data from a dictionary, the fastest is to loop over it using `for key, value in dictionary.items():` which will give you the key and value pairs, would that work for you?

Comment: done i have check mark to your  answer Thankyou again   fsimonjetz

Answer (score 0):

```
Context = {}
 i = 0

 for item in data:
    Context[f”item{i}”] = item.attribute
    i++
```

Comment: Thankyou yousef i appreciate your answer i vote you as well